# Storing a jQuery element in chrome.storage

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will get any element that is clicked on and  store it in chrome.storage for reference later.

I am able to store the clicked element as a string then set it in the storage, but this is hitting the storage limits quite quickly.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
"key": elementAsString
    }, function () {
getStorage();
});
```

I need some advice on the best way to go about this.

Storing a reference to the element in the form of a class name is also problematic, as I want to iterate over the stored items at a later date and change them. This will only work if each element has a unique class/id name (I would like to reference individual sentences, for example).

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this that I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you need to store the whole element? In any case, you can't store it much more efficiently as an object. You either need to store only properties you need (preferable) or serialize and compress the string with, say, gzip.

Comment: I mean, why would you even want to store an element (that only makes sense while you're not leaving the page) in `sync` storage?

Comment: Like I said, I thought I was doing something wrong (brand new to this stuff). The idea is the elements are hidden onClick, before being added to the storage. Then hidden again when the page is reloaded.
Thanks for the help anyway, I need to rethink how to do this or look at serializing.

Comment: When the page is reloaded, the DOM is rebuilt anew, and the stored elements are no longer valid (not present in the DOM).